# The mark "â€‹â€‹" is showing up in my CSS and appears to be breaking everything after it. What could be causing this?

Tags: css, flashdevelop

As per the question, I am attempting to figure out where "â€‹â€‹" is coming from in my CSS. I use FlashDevelop, and up until now, it has worked fine. I have a min file I'm uploading to the site, and â€‹â€‹ appears at the end of it, sometimes in the middle before the last little rule. Has anyone else encountered this kind of problem before? My CSS is mostly just class rules, rather basic defining columns. I am using Bootstrap and Font Awesome alongside it, but this just started happening today.

This is my code pre-minify:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e6eded;
}

.box {
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    background: #aafed6;
}

.header {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #818181;
}

.left {
    float: none; /* not needed, just for clarification */
    background: #e8f6fe;
    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}​​
```

After FlashDevelop produces the minified file and uploads it, I get this:

```
html,body{height:100%;background-color:#e6eded;}
.box{height:auto;overflow:hidden;}
.right{width:240px;float:right;background:#aafed6;}
.header{height:55px;background-color:#818181;}
.left{float:none;background:#e8f6fe;width:auto;overflow:hidden;}
â€‹â€‹
```

This is the remainder of the template I'm working on as requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Teonnyn.com</title>

    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <?PHP echo $this->Html->css("bootstrap.min"); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <?PHP echo $this->Html->css("main.min"); ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="header">


    </div>

    <div class="right">
        Test
    </div>      


    <div class="left">


    </div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure it is a UTF encoding issue.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Comment: UTF is what i thought immediately, i am afraid we wil have to see at least the Html head section and the whole css file(s).

Comment: Normally you have to add something like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` to your header. Can't be sure without seeing your html header and css file.

Comment: Edited the question to show the rest of the in-development template.

Comment: "â€‹" is the Latin-1 representation of the byte sequence "E2 80 8B", which represents (in UTF-8 encoding) the [Zero Width Space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) (U+200B). Chances are that you can't *see* the character in an editor, since it is zero-width, but maybe this info gives you a hint how to hunt it it down.

Comment: That was it, Tomalak. I found it hidden in the file using WordPad, couldn't find it via FlashDevelop directly. Quick edit fixed and got rid of the issue, which has not returned.

Comment: Hint: Mentioning my name is not enough, if you want to notify me, put an @ in front of it. I can write that as an answer, or you can answer your own question and I'll upvote. As you like.

Answer (score 0):

@Tomalak provided the correct answer. While I had to hunt for the symbol, opening a plain text editor displayed the actual code and allowed me to delete it correctly.